# How to access a dataframe within a different module?

Tags: python, dataframe

Let's say I have 4 modules: main.py, a.py, b.py, c.py

So the main file is supposed to call all 3 modules (a,b,c)

Now let's say a.py contains a query, which outputs a dataframe that I need to use both b.py and c.py. How do I access the dataframe results produced in a.py from b.py and c.py without having to re-execute the whole query?

Thanks

Comment: sounds almost as though you're going to run into a circular dependency but its unclear what exactly you're asking

Comment: simply put, i just want to re-use the dataframe results from a.py in b.py and c.py. I don't want to re-run the query 3 times to get the same results in each module.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure if this is what you're asking but you can try to use main to obtain the dataframe from a and then have methods which load the dataframe in b and c

```
# main.py
df = a.get_df()
b.load(df)
c.load(df)
```